# Laravel 5.2 App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm confused, when I use `php artisan route:list` in **laravel 5.2** I get a bunch of URLs and methods which are executed by visiting the specific url. for example, when I visit laravel.app/register it shows registration form, I can find the controller but not the function(method) called ShowRegistrationForm. 
*where can I find that **ShowRegistrationForm** ?*  I just dont see how it works.

```
| Domain | Method   | URI                     | Name | Action                                                          | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                       |      | Closure                                                         |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | articles                |      | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@index                   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | articles/create         |      | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@create                  | web        |
|        | POST     | articles/store          |      | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@store                   | web        |
|        | PATCH    | articles/{id}           |      | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@update                  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | articles/{id}           |      | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@show                    | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | articles/{id}/edit      |      | App\Http\Controllers\ArticlesController@edit                    | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                    |      | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                       | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                   |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm          | web,guest  |
|        | POST     | login                   |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login                  | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD | logout                  |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@logout                 | web        |
|        | POST     | password/email          |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail | web,guest  |
|        | POST     | password/reset          |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@reset              | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token?} |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm      | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD | register                |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm   | web,guest  |
|        | POST     | register                |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register               | web,guest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `AuthController` uses the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait, which in turn uses the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers` trait.

If you open up that file, you'll see the methods you are looking for: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    if (property_exists($this, 'registerView')) {
        return view($this->registerView);
    }
    return view('auth.register');
}

public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }
    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->create($request->all()));
    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Edit: PHP 5.4 introduced ["traits"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). Think of traits as reusable pieces of code. I think the easiest way to explain this is to think of them like copying/pasting. You create a trait that has some common functionalities. Then, when you "use" the trait, it inherits all those properties and methods.

Answer (score 0):

what would be the approach to send data from registration to two different tables? would be this a good idea or its totally wrong idea ?

```
protected function create(array $data) {

        $user = User::create([
                    'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
                    'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
                    'middlename' => $data['middlename'],
                    'usertype' => $data['usertype'],
                    'email' => $data['email'],
                    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
        $company = Company::create([
                    'ICO' => $data['ICO'],
                    'user_id' => $user['id'],
        ]);
        return $user;
    }
```